# Creating a diary app but can not get the text from the text view to be saved in the firebase data base

Tags: java, android, json, firebase

I'm trying to create a diary where the users can write their diaries with a title and have it saved in the Firebase Database. The code should function as follows:

The user types in the title and the diary in the corresponding textviews and when "submit" is clicked, the information will be saved in the firebase database as a string. Later on I would like to also retrieve that data but for now, I'm just trying to get the data to save to the database. The app keeps crashing so I can't even get it to start.

Below is the java code:

```
public class draft extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView diary;
    TextView titlee;

    Button submit;

    DatabaseReference mDatabase;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        diary  = findViewById(R.id.Diary);
        titlee = findViewById(R.id.Title);
        submit = findViewById(R.id.Submit);



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_draft);




        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference mDatabase = database.getReference("diary");
                String fdiary =diary.getText().toString();
                String ftitle =titlee.getText().toString();
                String userId = mDatabase.push().getKey();
                diaryclass userDiary = new diaryclass(ftitle,fdiary);
                mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(userDiary);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

and below is the diary class java file

```
public class diaryclass {

    public  String Title;
    public  String Diary;

    public  diaryclass(){

    }

    public  diaryclass(String Title,String Diary){
        this.Title=Title;
        this.Diary=Diary;
    }

}
```

below is a picture of the xml view so it is easier to imagine the view

[image: below is a picture of the xml view so it is easier to imagine the view]

---

## Solved

using this modification the code now works

```
            String diaryTitle =  titlee.getText().toString();
            String diaryContent = diary.getText().toString();
            String userId = mDatabase.push().getKey();
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("Diary", diaryContent);
            hashMap.put("Title", diaryTitle);
            mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(hashMap);
            titlee.setText("");
            diary.setText("");
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: If the answer helped you, would you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Comment: TheLegendOf9gag, that is essentially the answer I gave you without the `.setText()`. Since my answer helped you, can you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: @TheLegandOf9gag did my answer not help you? Your solution seems to be exactly the same as mine except for two lines of code that pertain to your project specifically. Since my answer helped you, can you please **mark it as accepted**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try using HashMaps to push the values? You can do it like this:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = database.getReference("diary");
        String fdiary =diary.getText().toString();
        String ftitle =titlee.getText().toString();

        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("Diary", fdiary);
        hashMap.put("Title", ftitle);

        mDatabase.push().setValue(hashMap);
    }
});
```

This saves the values in the database. Now, underneath one branch of the database you will have Diary: fdiary and Title: ftitle. To retrieve those values you can use a `ValueEventListener`.

Comment: thanks for the help i used your code and i updated the question with the code that works , just made a few modifications to it

Comment: Make value to Object in hashmap to allow hashmap used for multiple type of datatypes in Android

Comment: @TheLegandOf9gag, since you found my answer helpful and you used my code, would you please mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: sorry i forgot to do that xD